# Sorting alphabetically in a structure in C

Tags: c, list, struct

i wrote a structre that allows me to scan a name, surname, an area code and a telephone number.

When printing this list out, i want it to be in an alphabetical order. So far i have only learned to sort a list in C with numbers. This is how i would sort my list if i wanted to sort it by telephone number.

```
void el_insert(tparts partslist, tparts q){
     tparts p=partslist;
     while(p->next!=NULL && p->next->tel_nr<q->tel_nr) p=p->next;
     q->next=p->next; p->next=q;
return;
}
```

How would i change this if i wanted to sort it not by number, but by the alphabete? Could i use a similar code as here or would i need a different approach?

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp ? If yes please explain what got you stuck in using it for the sorting condition `p->next->tel_nr < q->tel_nr`. Ideally provide a [mre] with hardcoded sample input data (no reading input please, i.e. avoid `scanf()` etc.). Then making an answer for you will be easy.

Comment: Consider using -if allowed to- the [`qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). Also read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: Characters are numbers, check an ASCII table, so you just need a logic to use it for an alphabetical ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I used the first char to order the strings. Here is an example (I hard coded the array length in this):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char get_first_char(char* string);
void swap(char **str1, char **str2);

int main() {
    char *arr[5] = {
        "beta",
        "alpha",
        "zeta",
        "eta",
        "sigma"
    };

    printf("Before order:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int min_id = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j ++)
            if (get_first_char(arr[j]) < get_first_char(arr[min_id])) {
                min_id = j;
            }
        swap(&arr[min_id], &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("After order:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void swap(char **str1, char **str2) {
    char *temp = *str1;
    *str1 = *str2;
    *str2 = temp;
}

char get_first_char(char* string) {
    return string[0];
}
```

Output:

```
Before order:
0. beta
1. alpha
2. zeta
3. eta
4. sigma
After order:
0. alpha
1. beta
2. eta
3. sigma
4. zeta
```

Hopes this help a little bit.

Comment: @hsv1887vdv
Did you succeed?